# Agregar mas información que solo .tittle y .snippet en Marcador

Tags: java, android, google-maps

En una base de datos tengo información como nombre, dirección, teléfono, etc. y esta la despliego en un marcador, pero MarkerOptions da las opciones de .tittle y .snippet por lo tanto solo puedo mostrar el nombre y dirección, estoy utilizando un infowindow personalizado pero aun así no logro saber muy bien como visualizar toda mi información, este es el código:

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_window_nombre"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info_window_imagen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Carlo Estrada Solano" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_window_placas"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info_window_imagen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/info_window_nombre"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Placas: SX5487" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_window_estado"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info_window_imagen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/info_window_placas"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Estado: Activo" />
```

CLASE INFOWADAPTER:

```
private static final String TAG = "CustomInfoWindowAdapter";
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public AdaptadorInforWindow(LayoutInflater inflater){
    this.inflater = inflater;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    //Carga layout personalizado.
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
    String[] info = marker.getTitle().split("&");
    String url = marker.getSnippet();
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_nombre)).setText("Lina Cortés");
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_placas)).setText("Placas: SRX32");
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_estado)).setText("Estado: Activo");

    return v;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}
}
```

MAIN:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = null;
    String url = "http://appserver.pu.gob.mx/movil/getLanLong2.php";

    try {

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url));
        location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", c.getString("id"));
            map.put("campo_latitud", c.getString("campo_latitud"));
            map.put("campo_longitud", c.getString("campo_longitud"));
            map.put("campo_nombre", c.getString("campo_nombre"));
            map.put("campo_categoria", c.getString("campo_categoria"));
            map.put("campo_estado", c.getString("campo_estado"));
            map.put("campo_titulo", c.getString("campo_titulo"));
            map.put("campo_descripcion", c.getString("campo_descripcion"));
            map.put("campo_publico", c.getString("campo_publico"));
            location.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

for (int i = 0; i < location.size(); i++) {      


        String name = location.get(i).get("campo_nombre").toString();
        String cat = location.get(i).get("campo_publico").toString();
        String tit = location.get(i).get("campo_titulo").toString();
        String des = location.get(i).get("campo_descripcion").toString();
 if(location.get(i).get("campo_estado").toString().equals("En proceso")&&location.get(i).get("campo_categoria").toString().equals("Ecolog?a")&&location.get(i).get("campo_publico").toString().equals("0")) {
            Log.d("Hola", "hola");

            //if (location.get(i).get("campo_publico").toString().equals("0")) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Hola",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //System.out.println(location.get(i).get("campo_descripcion").toString());
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(campo_latitud, campo_longitud)).title(name).snippet(tit).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_eco_yellow)));
                googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                            return null;
                        }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        View v = 
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
                        TextView names = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_nombre);
                        TextView adress = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_placas);
                        TextView category = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_estado);

                        LatLng ll = marker.getPosition();
                        names.setText(marker.getTitle());
                        adress.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                        Log.d(marker.getSnippet(), "hey");
                        //category.setText(ll.des.toString());
                        //category.setText(""+ll.longitude);
                        return v;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr esto toda la información que necesitaba la concatene en el mismo .tittle y .snippet y después cuando los iba a mostrar los separe con un salto de linea, haciendo referencia al control de la ventana personalizada. 
Aquí el código:

```
String name = location.get(i).get("campo_nombre").toString()+" 
"+location.get(i).get("campo_apellido").toString();

        String cat = location.get(i).get("campo_publico").toString();
        String tit = "Titulo: "+location.get(i).get("campo_titulo").toString()+"\n"+"Descripción: "+location.get(i).get("campo_descripcion").toString();
        String des = location.get(i).get("campo_descripcion").toString(); 


googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(campo_latitud, campo_longitud)).title(name).snippet(tit).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_eco_yellow)));

     googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                            return null;
                        }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
                        TextView names = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_nombre);
                        TextView adress = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_placas);

                        LatLng ll = marker.getPosition();
                        names.setText(marker.getTitle());
                        adress.setText(marker.getSnippet());                                               
                        return v;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Aunque ya lo has hecho, te comento que yo lo que hago es pasarle los datos que quiera mostrar en un array de Strings a través de la propiedad Tag del objeto Marker, creo que es más "elegante" que concatenar los datos en una cadena añadiéndole algún separador. Si te gusta puedo ponerte código para que veas mejor lo que digo

Comment: Si me gustaría, si busque varias formas de hacerlo pero la mas practica que me funciono para lo que quería fue esa. @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Answer (score 1):

Una solucion puede ser que crees un objeto Json con todos los campos que necesites, y convertirlo en String y pasarlo en el title, y adentro del InfoWindowAdapter, obtener el title y convertirlo en Json nuevamente para poder obtener las propiedades por separado.

```
//en donde creas tus marcadores
JsonObject datos = new JsonObject();
datos.addProperty("direccion","") //etc etc

mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(ubicacion)
                .title(datos.toString())


//en el Infowindowadapter en el getInfoContents
View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tu_layout, null);
TextView direccion = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_direccion);
JsonObject datos = gson.fromJson(marker.getTitle(), JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();
direccion.setText(
        datos.get("direccion").getAsString()
);//o tipo de datos/variable que necesites
```

Comment: Gracias, al parecer ya pude lograr lo que quería, concatenando los campos que quiero con en .tittle y .snippet y separandolos con un split. muchas gracias por respoder

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hago así, pasándole los datos a través de la propiedad Tag del Marker:

```
Marker marker= googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(punto)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                        .snippet(descripcion)
                        .title(titulo));
                //Aquí creamos el array donde le pasamos los datos
                String[] props = {"Prop1","Prop2", "Prop3", "Prop4"};
                //Aquí asignamos el array a la propiedad tag del marcador
                marker.setTag(props);
```

Para recuperar este array, en la clase INFOWADAPTER hacemos esto:

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(final Marker m) {
    //Carga layout personalizado.
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
    String[] info = m.getTitle();
    String url = m.getSnippet();

    //Aquí recuperamos el array
    String[] props = (String[])m.getTag();
    //Ahora ya puedes asignar los valores a los diferentes TextView que formar tu ventana de información del marcador
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_nombre)).setText(props[0]);
((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_placas)).setText(props[1]);
((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_estado)).setText(props[2]);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: En la parte que dice //Ahora ya puedes asignar los valores a los diferentes TextView... ¿Como lo haces?

Comment: He editado la respuesta